# translate @aws-amplify/auth errors onto different languages

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, internationalization, translation

Could you please confirm if there are translations into different languages for @aws-amplify/auth errors such as AuthErrorStrings.

Or the only way we can add internationalization for @aws-amplify/auth errors is to manually add translations using I18n?
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/i18n/q/platform/js/

For example:

```
const dict = {
  fr: {
    'Authentication error: 'Erreur,
    'Email cannot be blank': 'Veuillez fournir un courriel'
  },
  es: {
    'Authentication error': 'Error,
    'Email cannot be blank': 'Please provide an email'
  }
};

I18n.putVocabularies(dict);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi also have same issue. is it possible?